# RegisterStartupScript in User Control causes Event Validation error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, eventvalidation

I have the following code in the code behind for a user control attached to a simple button click event.  How do I avoid this cause an invalid postback?  Its generating an Event Validation error.

```
protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateEditControls();
    pnlEditDialog.Visible = true;

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
       this.GetType(),
        "navigate",
        "window.onload = function()
              {window.location.hash='#editDialog';}",
       true);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your solution below in a separate answer, and accept that one instead? The answer you just accepted is a [literal copy-paste from elsewhere](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Caller%2C+typeof(Caller\)%2C+%22Script+Name%22%2C+Script.ToString(\)%2C+true\)%3B%22+%22The+Script+manager+has+trouble+adding+scripts+to+the+Page+object+from+a+user+control+and+must+have+a+reference+to+the%22), and not specifically written for your question. It would be more helpful for future visitors to have an answer which explains what's wrong on top of the code.